# Enabling support for multiple user logins with different themes?

Tags: c#, authentication, themes, authorization, multi-tenant

I have two roles set up in my web application one 'admin' and one 'operations', and two themes blue and red.

What I want to be able to do is build an introductory multi tenancy application which allows for 2 different user logons accessing differentiating themes?.

Now, I can switch themes dynamically using a drop down menu, but am struggling to piece together the code that would allow this when dealing with 2 different user accounts?.

Im working in public void Page_PreInit() event.

Any advise would be great, cheers.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public void Page_PreInit()
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole("admin"))
        {
            Page.Theme = red;
        }
        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("operations"))
        {
            Page.Theme = blue;

        }
    }


    public string red { get; set; }

    public string blue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to switch based on the user's role.

```
 protected void Page_PreInit()  {
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("admin"))
    {
        Page.Theme = Profile.Blue;
    }
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("operations"))
    {
        Page.Theme = Profile.Red;
    }  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is a link if you want to see some related documentation: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/themes/personalization.aspx#code

Comment: Added code to the question, it doesnt seem to be using the correct theme for each role

Comment: a page is displaying but neither theme is used

Comment: Make sure your App_Themes folder include a red folder and a blue folder. For Example: 

-App_Themes
---red (folder)
-----Default.css 
---blue (folder)
-----Default.css

Comment: I have checked the naming conventions and both themes are in the app themes folder.